# mysql to get depth of record, count parent and ancestor records

Tags: mysql, count, parent, depth

Say I have a post table containing the fields `post_id` and `parent_post_id`. I want to return every record in the post table with a count of the "depth" of the post. By depth, I mean, how many parent and ancestor records exist.

Take this data for example...

```
post_id   parent_post_id
-------   --------------
1         null
2         1
3         1
4         2
5         4
```

The data represents this hierarchy...

```
1
|_ 2
|  |_ 4
|     |_ 5
|_ 3
```

The result of the query should be...

```
post_id   depth
-------   -----
1         0
2         1
3         1
4         2
5         3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just found this post. Seems I'm stuck maintaining the depth in a column since a nested model is not appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195863/mysql-calculate-depth-in-a-parent-child-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're making a lot of queries like this, you may find that a nested set model is more appropriate than the adjacency list you're asking about. There's a good discussion of both models [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

In any event, to do what you're asking with an adjacency list you're looking at either recursion in the application layer, or storing the level as a 3rd column.

ETA: if your level count isn't terribly high, you can do it with self joins:

e.g. nodes with 2 ancestors:

```
SELECT t1.node 
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.parent = t2.node
JOIN mytable AS t3 ON t2.parent = t3.node
WHERE t3.parent IS NULL;
```

Comment: My issue with nested sets is that Ill be doing a lot of inserts and I dont want to be doing tons of left and right index adjustments. I imagine youre right and I will just need to store the depth in a column and maintain it. Bummer.

Comment: @Nate: check my ETA. It's not too horrible if the depth isn't excessive.