# Find depth of user in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table where `user_id` and `parent_user_id` is stored. For example:

```
user_id    parent_user_id
--------------------------
1          0
2          1
3          2
4          3
5          4
```

Now if I want to know the depth of `user_id` 5,(which is 5) how can I get it? I tried a lot of queries mentioned here in SOF but none solves my case. All I want is query to tell me depth by traversing like 5->4, 4->3 .. 1->0. Please help me guys.

**UPDATE** :

Some queries which I have tried

```
select user_id, @pv:=parent_id as 'parent_id' from user_referral
join
(select @pv:=7)tmp
where user_id=@pv;   

SELECT t1.user_id, t1.parent_id FROM
user_referral AS t1 LEFT JOIN user_referral as t2
ON t1.user_id = t2.parent_id
WHERE t2.user_id = 9 ORDER BY t2.referral_id;
```

But none worked as expected. One funny thing, none give me answers in recursive way and each query gave mu just 1 record!

Some links which I have tried :

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824033/mysql-to-get-depth-of-record-count-parent-and-ancestor-records)

[Link2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73072/summarize-from-unlimited-level-depth-parent-child-in-mysql)

Comment: look for recursive query..

Comment: please post what you have done so far.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. This seems to be exactly the same as the first link you posted, so why didn't that solution work?

Comment: See also http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @Barmar In my case, it is reverse traversal. from 5->4... . So it wasn't working.

Comment: It looks the same to me. In the other question, it's `5->4->2->1` and the depth is `4`.

Comment: No, it was ascending order. I tested. Testing recursive queries now.

Comment: @almasshaikh: MySQL does not support recursive queries

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess I have to do this in a Java method, *sigh* If any other idea to find depth of user_id will be helpful. Thanks a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some RDBMS products offer built in hierarchical querying. For example, [Oracle SQL has](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) a `START WITH ... CONNECT BY` syntax.

But not MySQL. You have to fake it somehow. One way is to retrieve the data and build the hierarchy in your application's memory.

Another way is with a sequence of `LEFT JOIN` operations that's longer than the expected depth of the hierarchy. This query gets a bit ugly, but it works. Each row of such a query contains the "genealogy" of the row.  Here's an example for your data (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/128372/4/0):

```
select a.user_name,
       COALESCE(g.user_id, f.user_id, e.user_id, d.user_id, c.user_id, b.user_id, a.user_id) root,
       (a.user_id IS NOT NULL) + (b.user_id IS NOT NULL) + (c.user_id IS NOT NULL) +
       (d.user_id IS NOT NULL) + (e.user_id IS NOT NULL) + (f.user_id IS NOT NULL) +
       (g.user_id IS NOT NULL) depth
  from hier a
  left join hier b on a.parent_user_id = b.user_id
  left join hier c on b.parent_user_id = c.user_id
  left join hier d on c.parent_user_id = d.user_id
  left join hier e on d.parent_user_id = e.user_id
  left join hier f on e.parent_user_id = f.user_id
  left join hier g on f.parent_user_id = g.user_id
  order by depth DESC
```

The logic that's coded into `CONNECT BY parent_user_id = user_id` in an Oracle hierarchical query shows up here as the repeated `ON` clauses for the repeated `LEFT JOIN` operations.

Comment: Actually MySQL is one of the *few* DBMS to not support recursive queries. Nearly all DBMS can do that nowadays.